# Why accessing a global variable inside a function is erroneous, when there's a local variable with the same name assigned in the next line?

Tags: python

```
a=1

def func():
    print(a)
    a=2

func()
```

The code above issues the following error:

> local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Given the imperative nature of Python i expect that the variable `a` is treated like a global variable before the Interpreter reaches the next line, where the variable `a` is assigned again but as a local variable (since it happens inside the function).

Comment: This should answer your question: [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: Python source code is not interpreted; Python *byte* code is, and you get the byte code by *compiling* the source code. During compilation, the code generator needs to know if `a` is local or not, and that decision is made once for the entire scope: it cannot change from line to line.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp says "Variables that are created outside of a function are known as global variables."

Comment: That's a gross oversimplification.

Comment: It's the way the language handles locals vs. globals.  If you declare `global a` within the function, then all references to `a` within the function refer to the global.  If you don't declare `global a`, but don't assign to `a` within the function, then all references again refer to the global.  But if you don't declare `global a`, and you do assign to `a` within the function, then all references to `a` within the function refer to the local variable.  In this case, if you try to access its value before assigning to it, you will get an error.